# php min max function not working properly

Tags: php

I have code to get minimum and maximum value from comma separated value ranges by using below given code

```
<?php

$price=$_GET['price'];
$grade = str_replace('-', ',', $price);

$number = array($grade);
$max = max($number);
$min = min($number);
echo "min value is $min <br/>";
echo "max value is $max <br/>";

?>
```

for the input **?price=0-5,4-30,6-50**  This should output minimum value 0 and maximum value 50 but my above code is giving output as

min value is 0,5,4,30,6,50 
max value is 0,5,4,30,6,50

Kindly guide me where i am making mistake or any other working alternate.

Comment: Your input is one item in your array. You will have to add each number as separate item to the array.

Comment: Replacing commas with dashes does not make a variable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `str_replace` method, you are converting a string into an array, your array looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => 0,5,4,30,6,50 )
```

With this array, you cant achieve or get the maximum and minimum value from an array.

You need to explode your string with comma as:

```
$yourArr = explode(",", $grade); // this will convert string into array.
```

Now your result should looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 30 [4] => 6 [5] => 50 )
```

**Complete Example:**

```
<?php
$price='0-5,4-30,6-50';
$grade = str_replace('-', ',', $price);
$yourArr = explode(",", $grade);
$max = max($yourArr);
$min = min($yourArr);
echo "min value is $min <br/>";
echo "max value is $max <br/>";
?>
```

**Result:**

```
min value is 0 
max value is 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect with creating an array. Please use explode for this. Explode function will break the string into array.

First parameter is the character on which you want to split the string and the second one is input. In your case it would be nice to add the str_replace function right there, **so you don't change the original input.**

```
$input = '0-5,4-30,6-50';
$numbers = explode(',', str_replace('-', ',', $input));
```

And now you can use min and max functions and they will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$price = '0-5,4-30,6-50';

if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $price, $matches)) {    
    $min = min($matches[0]);
    $max = max($matches[0]);

    var_dump($min, $max);
}
```

Output:

```
string(1) "0"
string(2) "50"
```

Comment: I did consider using a preg_split on the comma and dash, or splitting on non-digits.  But I think the preg_match_all is a better choice as it filters out possible input mishaps - concentrating only on the numbers/digits provided.